# Are custom validators run for django fields with a value of None or are they ignored?

Tags: python, django, frameworks, web

I have custom validators running on model fields in django (model-level validation). A lot of these fields have null=True so i have None occasionally for the value. It seems like the validators don't run (or at least don't raise errors) when the field value is None....

I can't find this discussed in the docs either. Is there a specified behavior for this or should I err on the side of caution and explicitly check whether the value is None first?

Comment: Why do you need to validate None?

Comment: Because a Field can be None. If I have a
'myfield = models.IntegerField(null=true, blank=true, validators=[myvalidator])', and the validation checks that myfield > 100, it doesn't make sense to do None > 100 when myfield is None (which it can be)